# API not executing? Confusion

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to get the Sentiment Analysis of a piece of texting using the Lymbix tutorial.

From research, I can use curl and when I want to execute the curl, use curl_exec();

But, I used a tutorial and have this piece of code:

```
    function sentimentToken($programming)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $data = array('article' => $programming);
    $headers = array ('AUTHENTICATION'=>'MY_API_KEY','ACCEPT'=>'application/json','VERSION'=>'2.1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://gyrus.lymbix.com/tonalize");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS,$headers); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($result);
}
```

But `var_dump($result)` Does not return anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: it's blank? or boolean false? false means an error occured, and you can get the error message with `echo curl_error($ch)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh here from Lymbix - we have several client libraries available to make it easier:

http://lymbix.com/client-libraries?client_library=ruby&__lsa=c4bbd4e8 for our list of client libraries

or

Straight from our github page:

https://github.com/lymbix/

Let me know if you need any help!

Comment: wow, for real? Also, I used one of the client libraries, it was really, really easy to implement and wasn't as confusing as the API calls.. So thank you for your reply :)

Comment: While this theoretically does answer the question, it won't if the link breaks. Can you expand on this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php):

> `curl_exec` returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

Given your actual options, you are not expected to have any data as a result, but rather an indication of success or failure.

Comment: Ok, I look stupid now. Can you suggest any tutorials in which I can use CURL to get API data back? For example, I can send a string of text and I get an actual data response that I can decode?

Comment: @Phorce: just use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to get the data back.